# teststack.white desktop automation tabitems under avalondock

Tags: ui-automation, avalondock

How to access tab items under Xceed.Wpf.Avalondock.Layout.LayoutAnchorable  for desktop application automation using teststack.white in .net

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this to get all the tabs.

IUIItem[] Tabs =window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Tab));

You can then access each individual tab by index Tabs[1], Tabs[2].  I set up a dictionary to keep track of what index pertains to which tab.

The downside of this is that if your window layout changes you have to update your tab indexing.

I am currently trying to find a better way around this, but this works in the meantime.